# bad_alloc on reading data from file

Tags: c++, fstream, bad-alloc

I have *.txt file with 1140736 double values (saved from matlab). There are also 1140736 rows - so one value per row. I want to process this data in C++ like that:

At the top of *.cpp file:

```
fstream winsigS("winsig_file.txt", std::ios_base::in);
double winsigVal;

double* winsig_f = new double[512];
```

And then simplified version of my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 557; i++)
{
    (...)
    for (int sig = 0; sig < 4; sig++)
    {
        (...)
        for (int k = 0; k < 512; k++)
        {
            winsigS >> winsigVal;
            sampleCounter ++;
            cout << sampleCounter << " " <<  winsigVal << endl;
            winsig_f[k] = winsigVal;
        }
        (...)
        // something happen with winsig_f
    }
}
```

So generally I calculate winsig_f myself but I want to debug/compare results with Matlab. So Instead of filling winsig_f myself I want to insert Matlab data saved to *.txt to it and iterate over it.

I get:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76a6c42d in SpeechRecogDSP.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0018fcec..
```

after sampleCounter reaches index 34816. But here are for sure 1140736 values in the file so why do I have bad_alloc exception? Also 557 * 4 * 512 = 1140736 so it's impossible to reach value that doesn't exist.

EDIT:
Okay I've just noticed that if I comment out other stream's in my code then it doesn't give bad alloc anymore. But I have 2 streams only for data saving. How can I work on more?

Comment: Can you use the debugger to see which line the exception came from?

Comment: I think it's some kind of memory matter. Because if I remove other streams from my code then - code I presented above works and reads whole *.txt.

Comment: So, can you use the debugger to see which line the exception came from? (It's a yes or no question... and if yes, which line?)

Comment: `bad_alloc` means you ran out of memory. The reasons for that are either that you didn't have enough memory or that you miscalculated the required amount of memory. BTW: Don't use `new` for arrays, use `std::vector` instead. This also keeps you from forgetting to release allocated memory, which then blocks available memory (a.k.a. memory leak), leading to allocation failures eventually.

Comment: @F1sher The problem is probably with the other streams you are using because as you said if you comment them out, the code works perfectly.